Why I see ajax response instead of view in my RAILS 5 app
I have button which submit login form. This button generate POST request for my session controller
Started POST "/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2024-04-03 10:49:13 +0300
Processing by SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"B1kNyKftmEga+Dz7UZ25m4KUDZCn5p7z1qdsC/r84gPhbD9hPNmc4q4WH4IJdos+QS0LDAm0YMX8YpxpzWtPCw==", "session"=>{"email"=>"mail@yandex.ru", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "lang"=>"en"} 

in route.rb
 post    '/login',      to: 'sessions#create'

But also I have ajax method for update user token
setTimeout( () => {
if (typeof user_grants !== 'undefined') {
  if(!channels['user_session']) {
    userSessionChannel = new Channel("UserSessionChannel");
    userSessionChannel.socketSubscribe();
    userSessionChannel.socketCallBack( {event: 'user_login'} , "user_session", userSessionWebsocketRouter);
    userSessionChannel.socketTrackConnection(toggleDisconnectedModal, 'offline', websocket_keep_alive);
    channels['user_session'] = userSessionChannel;
  }
  const jwtUpdater = new PeriodicRunner(() => {
    $.ajax({
      url: '/renew_jwt',
      type: 'GET',
      success: function (res) {
        if (res.ok) {
          app_config.jwt_encoded_user = res.data;
          ajaxSetup();
        }
      },
      error: function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      },
    });
  }, 300).start()
}

}, 0);
in routs.rb:
get   '/renew_jwt', to: 'application#renew_jwt'

in controller:
  def renew_jwt
    return render json: {ok: true, data: jwt_encode_user}
  end

def jwt_encode_user
  if Rails.env.stage?
    key = Rails.application.credentials.secret_key_base_dev
  elsif Rails.env.production?
    key = Rails.application.credentials.secret_key_base
  else
    key = Rails.application.credentials.secret_key_base_dev
  end
  payload = { user_id: current_user.id.to_s, exp: ((Time.now.to_f * 1000) + (60000 * 10)).to_i }
  response.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache'
  return JWT.encode payload, key, 'HS256'
end

And sometimes very rarely after login i see response for this ajax request  instead of result of my submit request.

My question is: Why I get this result?

It's very unclear what is going on here and what you even expect to happen. To start with you should really use MimeResponds for that action to ensure that the renew_jwt only responds to and with Application/JSON.

In other words, I start the process of rendering a new page, but instead I get ajax response as JSON. View should have been displayed, but instead of it - json
